# アクセスやエクセルのパスワードに使用できる文字は？

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-office

MS Officeのアクセスやエクセルで、パスワードとして使用できる文字を一通り教えてください。
キーボードから入力する文字はもちろんのこと、どこかのサイトで『Char関数で指定できるコードも使用できる』と見た覚えがあります。

アクセスを使用して、期間ごとに自動でパスワードが更新されるものを作ろうとしています。その作成したツールからしか開けないようなものを目指しているのですが、ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [ここ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements)の`Reference>2.The password contains characters from three of the following categories`は参考にならないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft 365オフライン版Officeの最新Execel(バージョン2112 ビルド 14729.20260)でxlsxファイルの「読み取りパスワード」について確認しました。

- 255文字までしか入力できませんでした。
- ASCII印字可能文字(U+0020～U+007E、空白も含まれていることに注意)は問題なく使用できました。
- ASCII印字可能文字以外の文字、例えば、平仮名や全角英字などがある場合は、下記内容の警告が表示されましたが、使用できました。

  > パスワードには、Microsoft Excel Macintosh 版に適切に変換できない文字が含まれています。パスワードには、英数字 (a ～ z、0 ～ 9) と記号 (!、@、#、$、%、^、&、*、(、)、+、=) の使用を推奨します。
- UTF-16ではサロゲートペアになるU+10000以降も使用できますが、1文字で2文字分(「**」と二つになります)になります。(例えば「吉」U+5409は255文字入力できますが、「」U+20BB7は127文字までしか入力できません。)

※ASCII印字可能文字以外は全ての文字種を試したわけではありません。例外がある可能性はあります。

オンライン版Officeでも開くことができました。Mac版OfficeやOffice Mobileについては確認していません。「書き込みパスワード」については15文字までになること以外は「読み取りパスワード」と同じでした。

内部実装としてはUTF-16でどんな文字でも受け付けそうですが、互換性を気にするなら、ASCII印字可能文字だけにしておくのが無難かとも思います。

WordやPowerPointについては同じOpenXMLとして仕様がまとまっているため、同じだと思われますが、Accessはデータ形式の作りが全く違うため、参考にならない可能性があります。

Answer (score -1):

1次資料ではなく、整合性も不十分ですが、こんな記事があります。

---

これだけはMicrosoftの資料で、大文字/小文字の区別があり、最大15文字の長さと記載されています。
[Protect a document with a password](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-document-with-a-password-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826)

> Passwords are case-sensitive and can be a maximum of 15 characters long.

---

こちらはMicrosoftの資料ですがポリシーの記事で具体的な文字種の話ではありません。
[Password policy recommendations for Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/misc/password-policy-recommendations)

---

[Office 365 のユーザー名、パスワードの要件|もくだいさんのOffice365至高のレシピ](https://mokudai.jp/knowledge-base/o365-admin/username-password-policy/)

> Office 365 のユーザー名、パスワードで使用できる文字を再確認します。
>   基本的にAzureADのユーザー名、パスワードの要件と同じです。
>
> パスワード
>
> - 下記4種のうち3種を使用する
>
>   - A – Z
>   - a – z
>   - 0 – 9
>   - @ # $ % ^ & * – _ ! + = [ ] { } | \ : ‘ , . ? / ` ~ “ ( ) ;
> - 8文字以上256文字以内
> - 変更したひとつ前のパスワードは利用できない

参考：[Azure Active Directory のパスワード ポリシーと制限](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy)
参考：[Password policies and restrictions in Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy)
参考：[「メールアドレスのルール」系まとめがそろって間違ってるのでご注意を](http://orgachem.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/26/015343)

---

[Office365ユーザ情報文字制限|SECIOSS](https://seciosscojp.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/204569234-Office365%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90)

> 3.Office 365パスワード
>
> 8文字以上16文字以下の範囲内で、下記4種類の中から最小限3種類を含める必要がございます。
>
> - 大文字 (A - Z)
> - 小文字 (a - z)
> - 数字 (0 - 9)
> - 次の記号: ! @ # $ % ^ & * - _ + = [ ] { } | \ : ' , . ? / ` ~ " ( ) ; < >
>
> ※SeciossLinkとシングルサインオン連携していればユーザのパスワードポリシーはseciosslinkに従いますが、連携用office365管理アカウントのパスワードはoffice365のパスワードポリシーになります。
>   ※山形括弧 【 < 】、【 > 】 につきましては、Windows PowerShell コマンドでの設定のみ有効でございます。
>   ※Unicode 文字、空白、ユーザー名 (ユーザー ID) のエイリアス (@ の前の部分) を含むことはできません。

---

[EXCEL パスワード保護　使用可能な文字|OKWAVE>パソコン・スマートフォン>ソフトウェア>Excel（エクセル）](https://okwave.jp/qa/q8950267.html)

> 試しに適当なセルに平仮名や漢字が含まれている文字列を入力してから、その漢字仮名交じりの文字列をコピーして、パスワードの入力欄に貼り付ける事でパスワードを設定しようとして見て下さい。

途中省略

> つまり、使用可能な文字は英数字(a～z、0～9)と!、@、#、$、%、~、&、*、(、)、+、=の記号だけという事の様です。
>   尚、...と言いましても、使用可能なのは半角文字だけであり、全角文字は使用出来ませんので注意して下さい。

ちなみに「英数字(a～z、0～9)」は「英数字(A～Z、a～z、0～9)」の間違いでしょう。